# Magento 2 - How to make all tab open at admin catalog product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product

I want to open all tab when I open admin catalog product page. Check below screenshot, in which I require to open all visible tab.

By default, all tab is closed when we edit catalog product at admin side.

How to make it all tab open?

[image]